# Protocol buffer in 64 bits vs2013

Tags: protocols, 32bit-64bit, protocol-buffers

Hi
I want to build my solution with VS 2013 64 bits, do I have to rebuild the latest version in 64 its or I can use the 32 ???
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What matters is the target. If you have a project for Platform Win32, all referenced libraries must be compiled for Win32 and if you have a project for Platform x64, all referenced libraries must be compiled for x64 (and with compatible compiler settings; visual studio has several project options that when changed make the libraries incompatible). Particular variant of VS 2013 does not matter.